# include filenames in addition to the rows being filtered with awk

Tags: awk

I have the awk command below that is selecting rows in multiple files based on the given criteria. To identify which file the selected rows come from I want to include the filename as part of the rows that are been printed.

```
awk '{ if($4 > 60*$2 &&$2>10 && $8="genus" && $10 !="unclassified") { print }}' *.tsv > out.txt
```

Comment: Soooooooo `print FILENAME, $0` ?

Comment: where should that be included?

Comment: What do you think `print` in your script does? [Here's a great awk introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: thanks. did not know that  $0 had to be included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '$4>60*$2 && $2>10 && $8=="genus" && $10!="unclassified" {print FILENAME,$0}' *.tsv > out.txt
```

Fixed `$8="genus"` which is assigning the value to `$8` instead of conditioning on it.  Your output is probably wrong.